# Call to a [[noreturn]] function and order of destruction

Tags: c++, noreturn

Considering following code, I or, rather the developer of original code, would expect that function-local object would be destroyed before the call to [[noreturn]] `fubar()` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Static
{
public:
    Static() { cout << "Static::Static" << endl; }
    ~Static() { cout << "Static::~" << endl; }
};

class Automatic
{
public:
    Automatic() { cout << "Automatic::Automatic" << endl; }
    ~Automatic() { cout << "Automatic::~" << endl; }
};

[[noreturn]] void fubar() {
    cout << "It's FUBAR" << endl;
    throw 42;
}

void foo() {
    Automatic a;
    static Static b; 
    
    fubar();
    cout << "It's fine." << endl;
}

int main()
{
    try {
        foo();
    }
    catch(int a)
    {
        cout << "main() was FUBARed. Answer is " << a << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Apparently that's not true. E.g. output after compiling with GCC 10 shows that `Automatic` was destroyed after `fubar` was entered, but it happens before exception was caught. It's exactly same behaviour as if fubar() wasn't `noreturn`.

```
Automatic::Automatic
Static::Static
It's FUBAR
Automatic::~
main() was FUBARed. Answer is 42
Static::~
```

Is that a defined behaviour? It is a result of stack unwinding for exception handling. Further investigation shows that `exit(0);` (which is declared as `[[noreturn]]` itself).

```
[[noreturn]] void fubar() {
    cout << "It's FUBAR" << endl;
    exit(0);
}
```

result to incomplete destruction of automatics:

```
Automatic::Automatic
Static::Static
It's FUBAR
Static::~
```

Does this actually mean that calls to [standard functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/noreturn) declared as [[noreturn]] is a big "no" for an OS that doesn't do clean-up after process execution and that the use of local variables to initialize any OS-wide resources is not safe if any such call is possible (no proper deinitialization will happen) or I'm finding a flaw?

Comment: _"I or, rather the developer of original code, would expect that function-local object would be destroyed before the call to [[noreturn]] fubar() function."_ Why?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings because their concept of C++ as OOP language as it given by education system suggests that  brace-enclosed block de-facto was exited, the object will be destroyed (they don't know of technical, "hardware detail" of stack unwinding or `atexit`).. The problem is that framework their are using put them in a corner without any options unless there will be some careful use of `std::atexit` to free critical resources which implies architecture designed for such. QtQuick, actually contains similar errors, in certain scenarios, leading to QtQuick engine process leaving a zombie.

Comment: They don't need to know about hardware details of stack unwinding or `atexit`. They only need to know the rules of how and when local variables are destroyed, and that nowhere (as far as I can tell) states that this changes when the function calls a `[[noreturn]]` function. I'm struggling to grok the premise of this question. Why do you think `[[noreturn]]` would affect object lifetime? Where did you read this?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Most devs don't read standard as I found to my sadness.  ANd that conclusion happens from how educational material show it. SUpported by implementation of "big"  libraries use of terminate or exit. which do that and on some platforms that doesn't cause problems, e.g. Windows does system-wide clean-up anyway . Linux doesn't. Some kiosk OSes doesn't even clean up heap.

Comment: Again, you do not need to read the standard, only the chapter on local variables in an introductory textbook on C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's exactly same behaviour as if `fubar()` wasn't `noreturn`.

As expected; `[[noreturn]]` is a red herring here, as the `fubar()` does not return (and thus fulfills the requirement that the attribute is intended to signal).

From [[dcl.attr.noreturn]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.attr.noreturn#2) and [[dcl.attr.noreturn]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.attr.noreturn#3) [**emphasis** mine]:

> **/2** If a function `f` is called where `f` was previously declared with the `noreturn` attribute **and `f` eventually returns, the behavior is undefined.** [ *Note:* The function **may terminate by throwing an exception.** *— end note* ]
>
> **/3** Recommended practice: Implementations should issue a warning **if a function marked `[[noreturn]]` might return**.

the `[[noreturn]]` attribute is only essential for functions that *do* return in some execution path (which is an error that a compiler *may* help flagging); namely that a function annotated as `[[noreturn]]` that actually does return results in undefined behaviour, and compilers are *recommended* to mark programs which contain returning program paths for `[[noreturn]]` annotated functions with a warning.

Comment: Funny, we look at (main) advantages of `[[noreturn]]` from two different points of view, implementer of `[[noreturn]]` functions, or user of such functions.

Comment: @Jarod42 T.b.h. I think it's a bit scary that we have an attribute that can lead to UB (by rule), but implementations are only _recommended_ to make use of the attribute to flag these kind of UB errors.

Comment: yes and it's misleading to the point that  generalized educational material skips that or misinforms by omission (resulting in idea "objects always will be destroyed when function exits").

Comment: Checking if function actually returns is not possible in general cases unfortunately (halting problem). Forbidding return statement might be problematic with possible used MACROs (which might create unreachable return statement) and doesn't solve void functions anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[`[[noreturn]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/noreturn) attribute is mainly to avoid warnings about missing return in non-void function.

They are several ways for a function to "noreturn":

- throw exception
- finish the application ([`std::terminate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate)/[`exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit)/[`abort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort), ...) which might or not allow/do unwinding.
- infinite loop

You have to read documentation about the "noreturn" function you call to know its behavior.
[`[[noreturn]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/noreturn) links std functions marked as such with their clean-up behavior.

Comment: So it's defined that `std::terminate/exit` may not do unwinding? because that's actually what is missing from description. The real situation came from program where unwinding through `throw` wasn't possible because of use of Qt framework and it does break global stack unwinding when exception is thrown by invading run-time handlers (and breaks it). The same framework's architecture results in such workflow where normal immediate exit isn't possible.

Comment: [`std::terminate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) calls `std::abort` by default, -> no clean-up. `std::exit` does clean-up (global variable) but no unwinding.

Comment: cppreference gives that kind of information pretty well. (see provided links).

Comment: sadly neither foreign language website nor foreign language standard doc aren't flying as certified source and state-certified source (aka educational material, which supposed to be based on standard doc, but it isn't) omits that. I'm hitting the wall there because I can't _legally_ say that they made a error. XD

Comment: You can still use actual standard, but it is not digest. "foreign" resources make it clearer (even if the might have error or over simplification).